# Blank blue screen with cursor Windows 11

Tags: cursor, blank-screen, windows-11

What happened: Blank blue screen with mouse cursor when unlocking PC (this doesn't always happen) No apps show a GUI.

What could fix the problem temporarily: Rebooting the computer or signing out and in.

Time left to downgrade to Win10: 2 days

How do I fix this (permanently)?

Comment: I have Windows 11 Pro Insider here running fine. Update all driver especially Video to see if that helps Run gitHub App Why Not Win11 and see how your computer stacks up. It should be running UEFI, Secure Boot, some version of TMP, and Directx !2

Comment: What you are using is a *pre-release* product. Even in "thoroughly" tested software, one expects bugs (e.g. updates that wipe out user accounts). You are enjoying the benefits of early adoption.

Comment: @John Yes, I am running UEFI, Sec. Boot, DX 12, and TMP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reboot your pc.
Try to open and close pc for around ten times till something shows in your screen(each time you open pc wait for 5-6sec to see if something is displayed on the screen)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.